# make menu like "facebook mobile menu" using latest jquery

Tags: jquery

I found this useful [jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/codefuze/HYjEB/1/) in creating mobile menu just like facebook, and I found out This method signature was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 1.9. jQuery, so is there any way to make effect like this using latest jquery.

```
$('#button').toggle( 
    function() {
        $('#right').animate({ left: 100 }, 'slow', function() {
            $('#button').html('Close');
        });
    }, 
    function() {
        $('#right').animate({ left: 0 }, 'slow', function() {
            $('#button').html('Menu');
        });
    }
);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/codefuze/HYjEB/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
var flag = 0;
var leftValue;
$('#button').on('click',function(){
      flag = !flag;
      leftValue = flag ? 100 : 0;
        $('#right').animate({ left: leftValue }, 'slow', function() {
            $('#button').text(function(i,v){
           return v == 'Close' ? 'Menu' : 'Close';
         });
        });
    });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HYjEB/1219/)

Comment: hi thank's for giving time to answer this question, your answer work like a charm, but there is little problem, it seems in first visit you need to click twice before the menu `slide right` http://jsfiddle.net/HYjEB/1216/ is there any way to click it just once in first load.

Comment: sorry for this dump question I just curious about that `flag` is the flag is responsible for the code to work?.. and also the 'menu' and 'close' is not changing.

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/HYjEB/1219/ and I'll describe later as I've some work...

Answer (score 2):

Try this [<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/4ajg614v/):

```
var flag=1;
$('#button').click(
    function() { 
        if(flag){
            $('#right').animate({ left: 100 }, 'slow', function() {
                $('#button').html('Close');
            });
            flag=0;
        }
        else
        {
            $('#right').animate({ left: 0 }, 'slow', function() {
                $('#button').html('Menu');
            });
            flag=1;
        }
    }
);
```

Updated code:

```
var flag=100;
$('#button').click(
    function() { 
            $('#right').animate({ left: flag }, 'slow', function() {
                $('#button').html(flag?'Close':'Menu');
            });
            flag=flag ? 0 : 100;
    }
);
```

## [Updated DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4ajg614v/2/)

Comment: is this posible to make the more shorter.. and by the way, thank's for this answer it also work..

Comment: in your update the `menu` and `close` not work as expected after click the menu the `label` must change into `close` and if I click the `close` the `label` should go back to `menu`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Bootstrap, this will solve ur problem.

http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/examples/navmenu-reveal/